# Issue establishing SCP with Public Network

Tags: stellar-core, nodes, network

I've successfully set up a watcher node on the TestNet and I'm trying to do likewise on the public network now. I've been using an adapted stellar-core.conf from the docs that looks like this:

```
DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=stellar user=stellar"

FAILURE_SAFETY=1

CATCHUP_RECENT=60480

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015"


NODE_NAMES=[
"GAOO3LWBC4XF6VWRP5ESJ6IBHAISVJMSBTALHOQM2EZG7Q477UWA6L7U  eno",
"GCJCSMSPIWKKPR7WEPIQG63PDF7JGGEENRC33OKVBSPUDIRL6ZZ5M7OO  tempo.eu.com",
"GC5SXLNAM3C4NMGK2PXK4R34B5GNZ47FYQ24ZIBFDFOCU6D4KBN4POAE  satoshipay",
"GBJZ7PUCL4UW3NDXCYZU5Q5EUOPMBCOP2FWJA4457LYUHCQUHDM2I2K4  icici",
"GAG5HH3VF7WLUR3TRQSJGNX66GSEA5HKH3QPIYREDCT4JXUCD4U43JBJ  poiuty",
"GCGWABAQ6OUOVUGWJVPRJ5LWBIWYN3CVOVOZYBNQQGIBRULQHYNGQ7GH  cryptomover",
"GD7FVHL2KUTUYNOJFRUUDJPDRO2MAZJ5KP6EBCU6LKXHYGZDUFBNHXQI  umbrel",
"GA4UZHDP44Q6NGZ6YXA7FMTFYPZIN3XLCUMMY2KUH5FX6TGEE4SEM42K  exodo",
"GCGB2S2KGYARPVIA37HYZXVRM2YZUEXA6S33ZU5BUDC6THSB62LZSTYH  sdf_watcher1",
"GCM6QMP3DLRPTAZW2UZPCPX2LF3SXWXKPMP3GKFZBDSF3QZGV2G5QSTK  sdf_watcher2",
"GABMKJM6I25XI4K7U6XWMULOUQIQ27BCTMLS6BYYSOWKTBUXVRJSXHYQ  sdf_watcher3",
]

KNOWN_PEERS=[
"core-live-a.stellar.org:11625",
"core-live-b.stellar.org:11625",
"core-live-c.stellar.org:11625",
"stellar.256kw.com",
"stellar1.tempo.eu.com",
"stellar.satoshipay.io"
]

LOG_FILE_PATH="/var/log/stellar/stellar-core.log"
BUCKET_DIR_PATH="/var/lib/stellar/buckets"

[QUORUM_SET]
VALIDATORS=[
"$eno", "$tempo.eu.com", "$satoshipay", "$icici", "$poiuty", "$cryptomover", "$umbrel", "$exodo", "$sdf_watcher1", "$sdf_watcher2", "$sdf_watcher3"
]


# Stellar.org history store
[HISTORY.sdf1]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.sdf2]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_002/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.sdf3]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/{0} -o {1}"
```

I'm having a strange issue where I see a lot of this in the logs, then stellar-core starts using 100% CPU and never leaves the "Joining SCP" state.

```
2018-02-04T17:13:00.374 GCSB7 [Overlay INFO] Dropping peer GAAAA@35.194.193.242:11625
2018-02-04T17:13:00.374 GCSB7 [Overlay WARNING]  connectHandler error: Operation aborted.
2018-02-04T17:13:01.390 GCSB7 [Overlay INFO] New connected peer 213.202.254.180:11625
2018-02-04T17:13:01.433 GCSB7 [Overlay WARNING] Received error (ERR_LOAD): peer rejected
2018-02-04T17:13:01.434 GCSB7 [Overlay INFO] Dropping peer GCXLL@213.202.254.180:11625
2018-02-04T17:13:04.394 GCSB7 [Overlay INFO] New connected peer 52.55.51.140:11625
2018-02-04T17:13:04.484 GCSB7 [Overlay WARNING]  connectHandler error: Connection refused
2018-02-04T17:13:04.485 GCSB7 [Overlay INFO] Dropping peer GAAAA@52.55.51.140:11625
2018-02-04T17:13:04.517 GCSB7 [Overlay ERROR] TCPPeer::drop shutdown socket failed: Transport endpoint is not connected [TCPPeer.cpp:405]
2018-02-04T17:13:07.406 GCSB7 [Overlay INFO] New connected peer 51.15.86.252:11625
2018-02-04T17:13:07.565 GCSB7 [Overlay INFO] successful handshake with GCIOB@51.15.86.252:11625
2018-02-04T17:41:33.189 GCSB7 [Overlay INFO] New connected peer 34.227.214.18:0
2018-02-04T17:41:33.501 GCSB7 [Overlay INFO] successful handshake with GCWHC@34.227.214.18:11625
2018-02-04T17:55:11.763 GCSB7 [Overlay ERROR] TCPPeer::writeHandler error to 34.227.214.18:11625 [TCPPeer.cpp:205]
2018-02-04T17:55:11.764 GCSB7 [Overlay INFO] Dropping peer GCWHC@34.227.214.18:11625
2018-02-04T17:55:11.832 GCSB7 [Overlay ERROR] TCPPeer::drop shutdown socket failed: Transport endpoint is not connected [TCPPeer.cpp:405]
```

The DB appears to be empty, the buckets directory has one small xdr file (100 bytes).

I'm new to this so maybe I'm missing something obvious. Or is it that the server instance is too small? It's 1 core, 1GB RAM but I've seen people say stellar-core can be run on micro AWS instances.

I installed stellar-core using `sudo apt install stellar-quickstart` and progressed from there.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for anyone else having the same trouble - I was using a template with some old/expired validators in it. You can get other examples from the docs and from [dashboard.stellar.org](https://dashboard.stellar.org).

Setting up for the first time can be tricky.

This was a noob question. But the next will be less noob :)